# grpc-gateway endpoints priority order

Tags: routes, grpc, grpc-gateway

I have a service defined this way :

```
service Service {
    rpc SearchCategory(SearchCategoryRequest) returns (SearchCategoryResponse) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            get: "/v1/categories/search"
        };
    }
    rpc GetCategory(GetCategoryRequest) returns (GetCategoryResponse) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            get: "/v1/categories/{id.val}"
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if I call `search?q=MyQuery`, it is caught by the `GetCategory` method and it tries to get the category with id `search`.

I suppose it is because the paths are very close. Is there a way of defining a priority in the routes like one would do in a classic web application ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question but I recently just ran into the exact same issue myself and found out the solution.

So basically, the **lower** you put your endpoint in your protobuf service definition, the **higher** it's priority.

For your case, you need to swap two endpoints so that `SearchCategory` is under `GetGategory`, which gives it higher priority.

```proto
service Service {
    rpc GetCategory(GetCategoryRequest) returns (GetCategoryResponse) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            get: "/v1/categories/{id.val}"
        };
    }
    rpc SearchCategory(SearchCategoryRequest) returns (SearchCategoryResponse) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            get: "/v1/categories/search"
        };
    }
}
```

then `/v1/categories/search` should work.

Answer (score -1):

Not use `{id.val}`, use `{id}`. And will be work

```
message GetCategory {
    string id = 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the problem does not come from here. It is related to the order of endpoints.

Comment: @c4k yea my bad, i for reproduce swap order